# In hashCode() for String, what's the reason for offset's existence? Seems redundant

Tags: java

Below is the source of `hashCode()` for `String`:

```
public int hashCode() 
{
   int h = hash;

   if (h == 0 && count > 0) 
   {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }

        hash = h;
   }

   return h;
}
```

`off` is initialized to `offset`, which is 0 (I looked everywhere in the source and each assignment made it 0 and that's all).  Then in the `for` loop, `val` is iterated through via `off` instead of `i`.  Why is this?  Why not just use `i` and eliminate the need for `offset` to begin with?  I assume there's a good reason for `offset` existing.  Any insight?

Comment: what if it is a substring of another huge string that is already in memory?

Comment: "I assume there's a good reason for offset existing. Any insight?"  Read the code of the `substring` method!!

Comment: *Below is the source of `hashCode()` for `String`* that belongs to OpenJDK and probably to HotSpot. Note that different JVM implementations can have different implementation of `hashCode` method of `String` class e.g. JRockit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The substring function creates a new String that has a value of offset other than 0.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
if (beginIndex < 0) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
}
if (endIndex > count) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
}
if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
}
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
    new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

This constructor is called.

```
// Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
this.value = value;
this.offset = offset;
this.count = count;
}
```

So offset isn't always 0.

Comment: Totally missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, strings can be defined as substrings of a parent string, to save space if you make many substrings of a huge string (such as to parse it). In that case they use an offset to determine where in the parent string they start.

Answer (score 2):

offset and count were used in older versions for substrings char array sharing. In current version sharing is not used anymore and these fields were removed. See hashCode impl from 1.7.0_15

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```